# Is getting all involved accounts of txs with state "processed" via webhook possible?

Tags: jsonrpc-api, confirmation, subscription, webhook

Is it possible to getting all involved accounts of a tx that has the current state "processed" via webhook?

I only managed to subscribe to the logs of new txs that are in the state "processed", for scraping involved accounts i have to wait until the tx reaches "confirmed" to call getTransaction, since that RPC call doesn't support tx that are not confirmed yet (https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction).

So my question is whether there is another way to subscribe to new txs with state "processed" that contains the involved accounts?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get the involved accounts of a transaction through a webhook when the transaction is in the "processed" state. The getTransaction method only returns the involved accounts for transactions that are in the "confirmed" state, as you mentioned.

One option you could consider is to subscribe to the logs of new transactions through the webhook, and then use the getTransaction method to retrieve the involved accounts for each transaction once it reaches the "confirmed" state. This would require you to keep track of the transactions you are interested in and make a separate request to retrieve the involved accounts for each transaction once it is confirmed.

Alternatively, you could consider using the getConfirmedSignature method, which allows you to retrieve the involved accounts for a transaction without waiting for it to be confirmed. This method returns the signatures for a transaction that have been included in a block, and you can use the getAccountInfo method to retrieve the account data for each of the involved accounts. This approach may be more efficient if you are interested in retrieving the involved accounts for a large number of transactions.

Comment: Thank you very much! Did you mean getConfirmedSignature though? I can't find a JSONRPC/web3.js call with that signature.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. After reviewing your question and the Solana JSON RPC API documentation, it appears that it is not possible to get the involved accounts of a transaction through a webhook when the transaction is in the "processed" state.

It is generally safer to wait for a transaction to be confirmed before acting on the data it contains. When a transaction is in the "processed" state, it has not yet been included in a block and may not be guaranteed to be included in the blockchain.

Comment: I still don't understand why the state of the tx would determine the amount of information i can extract out of it. Is there really no way? How are SPL arbers able to fire arbitrage tx within the same block or 1 block afterwards then? The tx wouldn't have even reached the state "confirmed" yet, no?

Comment: They probaly host their own nodes then